# Thinkpad brightness steps error using FN+Home/End

Tags: hardware, gnome, brightness, thinkpad, cinnamon

I've met the following problem: normally my T400 (Lenovo Thinkpad) has 16 steps of brightness, and Windows utilizes it correctly.

After a fresh install & minor tweaks Mint 12 (which is based on 11.10 Ubuntu) I only had 6 steps which was way to few.

Listing `/sys/class/backlight` showed 3 entried. I removed the `acpi-tools` package, one of the disapperared - and I now have 10 steps!

Therefore I think if I can reduce the entries to 1 I'm going to have 16 steps, since the stepping will be 1 instead of 2 (or 3).

```
/sys/class/backlight/

intel_backlight -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/intel_backlight
thinkpad_screen -> ../../devices/virtual/backlight/thinkpad_screen
```

The problem is that I'm unable to trace back what are the configs / daemons / kernel options triggers these two.

More strangely, I discovered a strange behaviour. 
I monitored

`watch -n1 "cat /sys/class/backlight/thinkpad_screen/actual_brightness"`

and

`watch -n1 "cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness"`

while changing the brightness with FN+home/end combinations from max to min. The outcome is the following:

```
brighness   intel       thinkpad
---------   -----       --------
MAX         2408475         7
|           1955115         5
|           1435640         3
|           1246740         1
|           1086175         0
|           1010615         6
|           859495          4
|           689485          2
v           481695          0
MIN         217235          0


brighness   intel       thinkpad
---------   -----       --------
MIN         217235          0
|           481695          2
|           689485          4
|           859495          6
|           1010615         7
|           1086175         1
|           1246740         3
|           1435640         5
v           1955115         7
MAX         2408475         0
```

When stepping from MIN to MAX, there's no difference between the last 2 steps.

Also, the OSD icon (Cinnamon desktop, default theme) goes from full to min in 4 steps and from full to min once again in 4 steps.

So... it seems that the `intel` entry is working correctly, showing correct values. The `thinkpad` entry however twists the things and even showing incorrect values.

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of the `thinkpad` entry?

System data:
Linux Mint 12 
3.0.0-16 kernel
Lenovo ThinkPad T400
Cinnamon 1.4 desktop

For any additional info, please tell me what do you need.

### EDIT

I'm sorry, I forgot to mention, I added `acpi_backlight=vendor` to GRUB cmdline as well, this is the result of the semi-better working than the default.